# Error ''Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.''

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-config

[Screenshot of error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNtkR.png)

I have got the above error while running the web application. I have recently installed ODTforVS2019 for the connection of oracle database because of getting the error which says that This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed. But now got this error while running my asp.net web application project.
It will be a great help for solving this error.
Thanks.

```
***My web.config file***

   

    enter code here<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="TNS_ADMIN=C:\Users\mahat\Oracle\network\admin;USER ID=SAGAR;PASSWORD=dell;DATA SOURCE=localhost:1521/xe"
      providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

trying to help but are you sure has both Oracle Data Access Client and Oracle Data Provider? it seems both are needed to establish access to oracle database from .net.
Source:
https://www.oracle.com/pt/database/technologies/dotnet-utilsoft-downloads.html

This seems very useful to know the differences between the needed driver/extensions
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_data_access_components_odac.htm